Is Pali the Buddha's native tongue?
Here is another non-essential question born from a dead thing.  Is Pali the native language of Buddha's birth town?  Apparently the Shakyas are bilingual (according to wiki), and they derived from a Munda people (according to wiki). Was Pali spoken by Munda people?  It makes me wonder if Buddha uttered, muttered the Pali b/c he was unfamiliar with it, or b/c maybe the language was a spontaneous birth? Instead, was Pali native to Magadha - according to wiki Buddha was born north of Magadha - where Buddha enlightened?
wiki (unreliable source) says:

Gautama Buddha, the founder of Buddhism, lived much of his life in the
kingdom of Magadha. He attained enlightenment in Bodh Gaya,


No, and actually the Buddha would have spoken many languages as also he taught the sangha to teach in the peoples language. So of course india/nepal all have multiple languages. I do know sanskrit was also NOT what the Buddha taught in. Sanskrit was more of a literary language, like latin is to western world today (dead language but used for literary purposes)  As for verbatim, again No. The sangha eventually wrote down what the Buddha taught but this was not until centuries after Buddhas death. Remembered and transmitted orally but of course nobody who wrote the teachings down was alive....

When Buddha taught. This is something you should always keep in mind, that what we are taught or what we read may be incorrect as it is not the actual words of the Buddha. We have to find out ourselves by practising what is taught. Also, keep in mind the kalama sutra.

related: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/30424/19249
